# What is lldb_expr in Swift Playground?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, oop, swift-playground

I was trying to demonstrate basic inheritance to someone and how the super initializer is always called by default when overriding an init:

```
class Animal{
    init(){
        println("Animal has been initialized!")
    }
}

class Dog:Animal{
    var feet:Int = 4

    override init(){
        println("Dog has been initialized!")
    }
}

var d = Dog()
```

Why is it that I get `{__lldb_expr_380.Animal feet 4}` on the last line? It goes away when I create an instance variable under the animal class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not 100% about this but to me this seems sane and logical.

Your `Animal` class is empty so the compiler needs a way to express / print the class / it's values. So what it does is print `__lldb_expr_380.Animal` because the compiler doesn't know what else to make of it. If you add a property, for example `legs`, the result becomes this: `{{legs 2} feet 4}`.

So, in my understanding whenever you have this empty superclass the compiler will get 'confused' and the error that happens is that it will just print out `__llb_expr_:some_number:.ClassName` instead of something like `{}`.

Reference: http://discuss.codewithchris.com/t/episode-7-classes-error---lldb-expr-/150

Comment: That absolutely makes sense! Thank you!

Comment: I gave a struct a couple of values, and it still returns that `expr` thing... Any idea why?