# What is this [__lldb_expr_19.Book] I'm getting in the console?

Tags: swift

I'm practicing the CRUD functionality in MVC design. Below I have a `Book` model and a `BookShelfModelController`. Everything seems to be working appropriately, but when I print to the console, all I get is this [__lldb_expr_19.Book]. If I have multiple books, then I get multiple like this[__lldb_expr_19.Book, __lldb_expr_19.Book].

This other StackOverflow answer ([What is lldb_expr in Swift Playground?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31020725/what-is-lldb-expr-in-swift-playground)) essentially tells me that the Book class is empty so the console doesn't know how to handle it. But my Book model isn't empty. How do I make it so when I print `bookShelfModelController.books` I get the book I added?

```
import Foundation

class Book {
    
    init(title: String, author: String, genre: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
        self.genre = genre
    }
    
    let title: String
    let author: String
    let genre: String
}

extension Book: Equatable {}

func ==(lhs: Book, rhs: Book) -> Bool {
    if lhs.title != rhs.title { return false }
    if lhs.author != rhs.author { return false }
    if lhs.genre != rhs.genre { return false }
    return true
}


class BookShelfModelController {

    var books: [Book] = []
    
    func create(book title: String, author: String, genre: String) -> Book {
        let book = Book(title: title, author: author, genre: genre)
        self.books.append(book)
        return book
    }
    
    func delete(book: Book) {
        if let index = self.books.firstIndex(where: { $0 == book }) {
            self.books.remove(at: index)
        }
    }
}

let bookShelfModelController = BookShelfModelController()

let firstBook = bookShelfModelController.create(book: "Foo", author: "Bar", genre: "FooBar")
let secondBook = bookShelfModelController.create(book: "Foo2", author: "Bar2", genre: "FooBar2")
bookShelfModelController.delete(book: firstBook)

print(bookShelfModelController.books.count)
print(bookShelfModelController.books)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the way Swift *describes* classes.

For a more meaningful way add this extension to adopt `CustomStringConvertible`. In the computed property return whatever you want

```
extension Book : CustomStringConvertible {

    var description : String { return "Book \(name) / \(author)" }
}
```

Do you really need a class? With a struct you get rid of the initializer, adopting `Equatable` doesn't require any additional code and you get a better *description* for free.

This can replace your entire class

```
struct Book : Equatable {
    let title, author, genre: String
}
```